# More accurate search of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating my own little autocomplete (not using jquery UI). On keyup of an input, I check my source array to see if I can match the user's input to anything:

```
var input_val = $input.val().toLowerCase();

$.each(array, function(i, suggestion){
    if(suggestion.toLowerCase().match(input_val)){
          //add the item to the autocomplete dropdown
    }
});
```

The problem I have is that .match() is too basic. For example, if the user types 't' in a location input field, a .match() will be positive for 'texas' but also 'fleet', as both have a 't' in.

I was hoping for a better way to search and/or match against the user input, starting from the beginning of the words in my array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
var input_val = $input.val().toLowerCase();

$.each(array, function(i, suggestion){
    if(suggestion.toLowerCase().indexOf(input_val) === 0){
          //add the item to the autocomplete dropdown
    }
});
```

This will check if the suggestion starts with the input value (since if the index of the needle ("t") in the haystack ("texas") is 0, it is at the beginning), and add it to list if it does.

Answer (score 3):

Do this

```
// Check if input_val is at the first position or index 0 in the suggestion
if(suggestion.toLowerCase().indexOf(input_val) === 0) {
      //add the item to the autocomplete dropdown
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use regular expressions to start the match at the beginning of the string with a carat ^

```
var input_val = $input.val().toLowerCase();

$.each(array, function(i, suggestion){
    var myRe = new RegExp("^"+input_val, "g");
    if(suggestion.toLowerCase().match(myRe)){
          //add the item to the autocomplete dropdown
    }
});
```